# How to customize Flyway so that it can handle CSV files as input as well?

Tags: python, csv, flyway

Has someone implemented the CSV-handling for Flyway? It was requested some time ago ([Flyway specific migration with csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830630/flyway-specific-migration-with-csv-files/)). Flyway comments it now as a possibility for the MigrationResolver and MigrationExecutor, but it does not seem to be implemented.

I've tried to do it myself with Flyway 4.2, but I'm not very good with java. I got as far as creating my own jar using the sample and make it accessible to flyway. But how does flyway distinguish when to use the SqlMigrator and when to use my CsvMigrator? I thought I have to register my own prefix/suffix (as the question above writes), but FlywayConfiguration seems to be read-only, at least I did not see any API calls for doing this :(.

How to connect the different Resolvers to the different migration file types? (.sql to the migration using Sql and .csv/.py to the loading of Csv and executing python scripts)

Comment: Is this a Java question or a Python question?

Comment: I want to be able to call a python (or a shell) file as a migration step in Flyway, which is written in Java. The Flyway API is java... so I guess Java.

Answer (score 0):

After some shed of tears and blood, it looks like came up with something on this. I can't make the whole code available because it is using proprietary file format, but here's the main ideas:

- implement the ConfigurationAware as well, and use the setFlywayConfiguration implementation to catalog the extra files you want to handle (i.e. .csv). This is executed only once during the run.
- during this cataloging I could not use the scanner or LoadableResources, there's some Java magic I do not understand. All the classes and methods seem to be available and accessible, even when using .getMethods() runtime... but when trying to actually call them during a run it throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I've wasted a whole day on this - don't do that, just copy-paste the code from org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.filesystem.FileSystemScanner.
- use Set< String > instead of LoadableResources[], way easier to work with, especially since there's no access to LoadableResources anyway and working with [] was a nightmare.
- the python/shell call will go to the execute(). Some tips:
- any exception or fawlty exitcode needs to be translated to an SQLException.
- the build is enforcing Java 1.6, so new ProcessBuilder(cmd).inheritIO() cannot be used. Look at these solutions: [ProcessBuilder: Forwarding stdout and stderr of started processes without blocking the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki) if you want to print the STDOUT/STDERR.
- to compile flyway including your custom module, clone the whole flyway repo from git, edit the main pom.xml to include your module as well and use this command to compile: "mvn install -P-CommercialDBTest -P-CommandlinePlatformAssemblies -DskipTests=true" (I found this in another stackoverflow question.)
- what I haven't done yet is the checksum part, I don't know yet what that wants.